# How to download file from aws s3 using python without using key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to download an xml file from AWS-S3.

I tried using `get_contents_to_filename(fname)` , it worked.

But i need to download the file without specifying `fname`, because if i specify the `fname` my downloaded file gets saved to`fname`.

I want to save the file as it is, with its name.

this is my current code

`k = Key(bucket)`

`k.set_contents_from_filename(fname)`

can someone please help me to download and fetch the file without using key.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which library you're using, but if k is the AWS key you want to download, then k.name is probably the key name, so k.get_contents_to_filename(k.key) would probably do more or less what you want.

The one problem is that the key name might not be a legal file name, or it may have file path separators. So if the key name were something like '../../../../somepath/somename' the file would be saved somewhere you don't expect. So copy k.name to a string and either sanitize it by changing all dangerous characters to safe ones, or just extract the part of the key name you want to use for the file name.